How many definite elementary integrals can be substituted between?
There are three types of definite integrals that I can think of. Those that equal $0$, those that equal $A\neq0$ and those that diverge through some manner. If
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=A\neq0$$
then we can form its normalised integral
$$\frac{1}{A}\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=1$$
Some examples would be something like
$$1=\int\limits_{0}^{1}dx\\
=\frac{1}{\ln(4)}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\operatorname{sgn}(x)-\tanh(x)|dx\\
=\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sec^{2}(x)dx\\
=\frac{2}{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{sinc}(x)\operatorname{sinc}(\frac{x}{3})\operatorname{sinc}(\frac{x}{5})dx$$
Given that these are all equal (because we're taking the normalised integrals) can we make explicit substitutions between them, to get from one to the other? The constants are just there for equality to hold, the meat is in the actual form of the integrand.
It's a similar story for those equalling $0$.
$$0=\int\limits_{1}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}dx\\
=\int\limits_{2}^{4}0dx\\
=\int\limits_{0}^{2\lceil{|z|}\rceil\pi}\sin(x)dx$$
These are equal, so can we manipulate substitutions to go from one to the other?
My initial guess for both is no. If we had an integrand with a non-elementary antiderivative, like $\ln(\sec(x))$, then it couldn't be related to $x$ because then there'd be a chain of elementary functions leading to it, giving it an elementary antiderivative.
Still, could all equal integrals with elementary antiderivatives be subbed between, and all those that also involve $\operatorname{erf(x)}$ be subbed between, and all those with both $\operatorname{Li}(x)$ and $\operatorname{Li}_{2}(x)$, and so on?

Nevertheless, I still think there's a concept of equality by happenstance. For some manifold, $|\partial \partial M|=-3.29i\zeta^{8}(-156)$, but is there really a deeper connection between the two? They're equal because they're equal. Compare that to $\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z}=\oint\limits_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{z}$ where it's true because it hinges on a fundamental underlying result that has a global-to-local property.

My apologies - I misunderstood the nature of your question. Of course, two integrations can have the same value without one having any real connection with the other. The set of all integrable functions on some set $S$ forms an infinite-dimensional vector space. The requirement $\int_S f = C$ for some constant $C$ is an affine subspace of co-dimension $1$. There are infinitely many degrees of freedom to change a function $f$ while keeping the integration value the same.
